# Django multiple annotate clashes

Tags: django, django-models

Check out the following code. I am trying to get the `area_count` annotation for which the correct value is 1. But if I add the `data_count` annotation to the 
queryset, `area_count` gets messed up.

```
>> factors_qs=Factor.objects.annotate(
    area_count=Count('change__areas'),
    evaluation_count=Count('factor_datas__evaluation'),
    )
>> factors_qs.get(pk=1017).area_count
>> 1

>> factors_qs=Factor.objects.annotate(
        data_count=Count('sets__elements__datas'),
        area_count=Count('change__areas'),
        evaluation_count=Count('factor_datas__evaluation'),
        )
>> factors_qs.get(pk=1017).area_count
>> 4615
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Count` with `distinct=True` argument:

```
factors_qs=Factor.objects.annotate(
        data_count=Count('sets__elements__datas', distinct=True),
        area_count=Count('change__areas', distinct=True),
        evaluation_count=Count('factor_datas__evaluation', distinct=True),
        )
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations):

> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong
>   results because joins are used instead of subqueries. For most
>   aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however, the Count
>   aggregate has a distinct parameter that may help.

Comment: Just did not have enough patience to read the documentation thoroughly.